# No alive nodes found in your cluster for magento 2.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch, controller, magento2

I am installing Magento 2.4.1 and have integrate Elasticsearch module. However, I'm facing the following issue:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException): No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

**Configuration Panel (Admin):**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaozU.png)

Comment: Are you upgrading from a previous version of Magento where Elasticsearch wasn't mandatory? Have you actually got an Elasticsearch instance? Have you checked its status? curl -i http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health

Comment: In my case this was caused by the Elasticsearch configuration with enabled SSL. Disabling it solved the connectivity problem. (xpack.security.http.ssl: enabled: false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Check the configuration

First let's check if your configuration is correct:

1. Update your host and port: '[host]:[port]'. E.g.: 'localhost:9200' in `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search` or if you are you are using Elastic Suite in `Stores > Configuration > ElasticSuit > Basic configuration`.
2. Update your indices alias name and indices name pattern in admin configuration same as above.

   [image]
3. Clear cache by going to `System > Cache Management` or using this command (on your server in Magento installation folder):

   ```sh
   bin/magento cache:clean
   ```
4. Reindex by visiting `System > Index Management` or running command below:

   ```sh
   # Update catalog search
   bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext 

   # Or reindex all indexers
   bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```

#### Check Elasticsearch

If the error still stands, it might be the issue with the elasticsearch service on your server. To solve this follow the steps below:

1. Log into your Magento instance.
2. Check if the elasticsearch is running:

   ```sh
   sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
   ```
3. Try to start it if it's not running, or restart it if it's running:

   ```sh
   # Start elasticsearch
   sudo systemctl start elasticsearch

   # Or restart elasticsearch
   sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
   ```

   You've found the issue if you encounter an error here and your elasticsearch doesn't start. Solve the issue first. Continue when the elasticsearch starts.
4. Navigate to your Magento installation folder
5. Reindex all indexers

   ```sh
   bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```
6. Clear the cache

   ```sh
   bin/magento cache:flush
   ```

Your problem should have been solved by now.

---

P.S. I believe this threat belongs to [Magento Stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com). I have already answered the issue [there](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/347190/100366).